# Combining two table without duplicates 

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table containing symbols:

Table1

```
'sym'
Ibm
Msft
SUnw
```

Table 2

```
'sym'
ABC
BCD
CDE
IBM
```

Using mysql: how could add the unique 'sym' from table 2 into table 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `distinct`, and add a `not exists` condition to filter out the symbols already in Table1:

```
insert  Table1
        (sym)
select  distinct sym
from    Table2
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Table1
        where   sym = Table2.sym
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "not exists" test:

```
       insert t1
       (sym)
       select sym from T2 where not exists
       (select sym from T1 where T1.sym = T2.sym)
```